# Converting ASCII string to integer using bitwise operators in C & vice versa

Tags: c, string, bit-manipulation

I am able to do this without using bitwise operators as below

```
int AsciiToInteger()
{
  char s[] = "Stack Overflow";
  int i, n = 0;
  for (i = 0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)
  {
    n += s[i]; 
  }

  return n;
}
```

How can I achieve the same using bitwise operators in C without using for loop?

Comment: This is (obviously) not the standard `atoi` function, it's probably a good idea to use a different name, and explain what you want to achieve. I don't see you using bitwise operators anywhere in the code – which may or may not be your point, I didn't understand that part at all, especially since I'd expect `atoi` to work without them, in the obvious implementation – and why do you expect to be able to do anything with an arbitrary-length string without a loop?

Comment: @ Christopher , you are right . This has nothing to with standard function. I was just wondering if this could be done using bitwise & not using for loop.

Comment: Who upvoted this question?  It doesn't make any sense at all, currently.

Comment: Since ALUs work that way, it is obviously possible to implement addition using bitwise operators, but what's the point? It would be slower and harder to read&write. You can exchange the for loop for another loop construct, but unless you know at compile time how large the strings will be, you can't do without a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same without a `for` loop using recursion:

```
int AsciiToInteger(const char * Str)
{
    if(*Str)
        return (int)*Str + AsciiToInteger(Str+1);
    else
        return 0;
}

/* ... */
int n = AsciiToInteger("Stack Overflow");
```

I don't know what bitwise operators have to do with this, you surely cannot use only them without a loop and without recursion *for arbitrary-length strings* (for fixed length strings instead the result would probably be something like unrolling the loop).

... but now that I read the comments I'm quite sure I didn't get the sense of the question... `:S`

Comment: Now I know why `atoi` has *undefined behavior* rather than just an unspecified value on overflow... >_<

Answer (score 0):

Except as an exercise in building higher level operations from bitwise operations, the task you're trying to accomplish is foolish. Don't do it.

As an exercise, the most important thing to realize is that you don't have to go back to the start every time you need to implement something new in terms of the building blocks. Instead you could write addition and subtraction functions in terms of bitwise building blocks, and put those together using the existing higher-level algorithm you've already got.

As for eliminating the loop, you could just unroll it to support a fixed max number of digits (the longest value that will fit in `int`, for example) unless you need to support arbitrary number of leading zeros. Recursion is a very bad approach in general and contrary to the whole "close to the metal" aspect of this exercise. Perhaps they just want you to avoid adding/incrementing a counter in the loop with "high level" addition, in which case you could use your bitwise adder function...

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons that loops exist is so that you can do operations an unknown number of times.  If you don't know how long your string is, you have no way of doing this without a loop.  Even if you do know the length of the string, why would you want to do it without a loop?